# How to set a transaction timeout in txpool properly?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

I want to limit transaction pending time to 5 seconds, after that the transaction considered as failed;

does `--txpool.lifetime`  solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop/reject transactions using **`Ethereal`** with an automated python script that encounters on every 5 seconds.

To understand more about **Ethereal**, Go through below link :

[Releasing Stuck Ethereum Transactions](https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/releasing-stuck-ethereum-transactions-1390149f297d)

Hope this answer will help You.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Mahesh's answer.

Transactions can't be cancelled or marked as failed. Once you submit a transaction to the network there is no way to cancel it.

The only thing you can do it *overwrite* the transaction. Note that this is just a trick and in reality it just means that you send *another* transaction to the network with the same nonce. If the new transaction has higher gas price miners will probably include that in a block first. Once that transaction is mined the older transaction becomes invalid as a transaction with that nonce has already been mined.

Comment: I don't really want to cancel it, but I want that the js promise reject or resolve something

Answer (score 0):

The `--txpool. lifetime` option doesn't directly solve this problem, as it's more related to the time a transaction remains in the transaction pool before being dropped.